# Why is ClaimsAuthorizationManager.LoadCustomConfiguration not being called?

Tags: c#, configuration, authorization, claims-based-identity, claims

I am trying to implement my own `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` following the examples on MSDN, mostly [this example project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Based-Authorization-89cf736e). The goal is to load policies from the project config file and use them to evaluate access control requests made by the application.

My custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` looks pretty much like the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Code below).

When I ran a TestSuite to test the `CheckAccess()` method, it failed. I debugged and noticed that the manager did not load the policies from the config file. **In fact, the `LoadCustomConfiguration()` method is never called, even though I registered the custom Manager in the config.** What could be the reason for this?

I am trying to test this within a TestProject, where my App.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" /></startup>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="Foo.Bar.ClaimsAuthorization.FooBarAuthorizationManager, Foo.Bar.ClaimsAuthorization">
        <policy resource="TestResource" action="TestAction">
          <or>
            <claim claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" claimValue="Developer" />
            <claim claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group" claimValue="Administrator" />
          </or>
        </policy>
      </claimsAuthorizationManager>
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is my custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.ClaimsAuthorization
{
    public class FooBarAuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<ResourceAction, Func<ClaimsPrincipal, bool>> Policies = new Dictionary<ResourceAction, Func<ClaimsPrincipal, bool>>();
        readonly PolicyReader policyReader = new PolicyReader();

        /// <summary> 
        /// Overloads  the base class method to load the custom policies from the config file 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="nodelist">XmlNodeList containing the policy information read from the config file</param>
        public override void LoadCustomConfiguration(XmlNodeList nodelist)
        {
            if (nodelist == null) 
                return;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                // 
                // Initialize the policy cache 
                //
                XmlDictionaryReader rdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(node.OuterXml)));
                rdr.MoveToContent();

                string resource = rdr.GetAttribute("resource");
                string action = rdr.GetAttribute("action");

                Expression<Func<ClaimsPrincipal, bool>> policyExpression = policyReader.ReadPolicy(rdr);

                // 
                // Compile the policy expression into a function 
                //
                Func<ClaimsPrincipal, bool> policy = policyExpression.Compile();

                // 
                // Insert the policy function into the policy cache 
                //
                Policies[new ResourceAction(resource, action)] = policy;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the principal specified in the authorization context is authorized to perform action specified in the authorization context 
        /// on the specified resoure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pec">Authorization context</param>
        /// <returns>true if authorized, false otherwise</returns>
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext pec)
        {
            //
            // Evaluate the policy against the claims of the 
            // principal to determine access
            //
            bool access;
            try
            {
                var ra = new ResourceAction(pec.Resource.First().Value, pec.Action.First().Value);

                access = Policies[ra](pec.Principal);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                access = false;
            }

            return access;
        }

        public bool CheckAccess(string resource, string action)
        {
            return CheckAccess(resource, action, Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
        }

        public bool CheckAccess(string resource, string action, IPrincipal principal)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (claimsPrincipal == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Principal is null or not of type ClaimsPrincipal!", "principal");
            var context = new AuthorizationContext(claimsPrincipal, resource, action);

            return CheckAccess(context);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my TestClass which I run using Resharper:

```
namespace FooBarTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ClaimsAuthorizationTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSuccessfulDemandAccess()
        {
            var username = "TestUser";
            var developerRole = "Developer";
            var roles = new[] { developerRole };
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
            var testUser = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
            Assert.IsTrue(testUser.IsInRole(developerRole));
            Assert.IsTrue(testUser.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, developerRole));
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = testUser;
            var authManager = new FooBarAuthorizationManager();
            var hasAccess = authManager.CheckAccess("TestResource", "TestAction");
            Assert.IsTrue(hasAccess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh, I just realized that I probably am not supposed to create the authManager myself. I have no idea though how to make the call to CheckAccess then.

Comment: I'm trying to build the code you supplied above. Can you tell me in which namespace I'll find the "PolicyReader" class?

I've tried searching on MSDN, but the only reference is to a sealed, nested class.

Comment: It's in the [CBA example project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Based-Authorization-89cf736e), here is the direct download link: [click](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Based-Authorization-89cf736e/file/54328/10/Claims%20Based%20Authorization.zip)

Answer (score 2):

I realized that my setup was correct, but that I was calling the custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` in the wrong way.

Because I was (wrongly) initializing the AuthorizationManager myself instead of using the one that the System creates based on the configuration, I circumvented the whole "LoadCustomConfiguration()" part.

**The solution is to call the ClaimsAutorizationManager that the system creates at Startup.**

I could not really figure out how to properly call it from a TestSuite environment (i.e. not from ASP.NET), but I found this helpful package which gives easy access to the currently valid ClaimsAuthorizationManager:

http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/

Now I can simply call it like this:

```
var hasAccess = ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess("TestAction", "TestResource");
Assert.IsFalse(hasAccess);
```

**UPDATE:**
Decompiling the source revealed, that this is a shorthand for

```
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager
```

which seems to be the proper way to get to the current `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`.

Comment: For me this way of using the registered ClaimsAuthorizationManager worked as well: 
`ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("TestResource", "TestAction");`